# Comparing remove white spaces

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the float value to remove the white space from it.

Here is the following is the example.

**In SQL Server**: In SQL Server I used the following script.

```
DECLARE @f1 FLOAT = 74.3658319091568;

SELECT REPLACE(@f1,CHAR(160),'');
```

--Output

```
74.3658
```

**PostgreSQL**: In postgresql I used the following script.

```
do
$$
DECLARE 
    v_f1 float = '74.3658319091568';
    v_f3 text;

BEGIN

    SELECT regexp_replace(v_f1::varchar, '\s+$', '') INTO v_f3;
    Raise info '%',v_f3;

END;
$$
```

--Output

```
INFO:  74.3658319091568
```

I didn't get the result as I get in the SQL Server.

Comment: A guess `SELECT to_char(float8 '74.3658319091568', 'FM999999999.0000');`??  Try like this http://pastie.org/10658654

Comment: @wingedpanther, What do you mean by --> `FM999999999.0000`?

Comment: FM (prefix ) -fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
do
$$
DECLARE 
    v_f1 float8 = '74.3658319091568';
    v_f3 text;

BEGIN

    SELECT to_char( v_f1, 'FM999999.0000') INTO v_f3;
    Raise info '%',v_f3;

END;
$$
```

`FM`(*prefix*) -fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

Using [data type formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE)

Answer (score 1):

Your Postgres `float` is a synonym for `real`, which has [6 digits precision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html). In SQL Server a default `float` has [15 digits precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You could use a Postgres `double precision` which also has 15 digits precision. There is no SQL Server type that has 6 digits precision.

Note: you normally don't get any whitespace when converting a `float` to a text type.  So replacing whitespace is useless (but also harmless.)

Note 2: in SQL Server, when using a fixed-length `char`, trailing spaces are removed.  So `REPLACE(@f1,CHAR(160),'')` replaces an empty string with an empty string.